# asp.net mvc 3 serverside remote validation not working on submit through fiddler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to understand how remote validation works. It works great client side or in browser. This is what I did, I need to check if a username exists while registration. So I added remote validation and it worked perfectly in browser. I wanted to test it on submit, so I captured the request in Fiddler and changed the username to something that exists and then submitted the request. It accepted. RemoteValidation did not occur (of course it failed at db). Hence doesn't it validate on server side?

Comment: Couple of days ago I thought that, too and I was lazy to do what you just did : diving into it.

Comment: I am having the same issue too.

Comment: @Jonna see this blog post : http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-mvc-server-side-remote-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hence doesn't it validate on server side?

No, of course that it doesn't validate on the server. It's just an AJAX call when you modify the value of the corresponding input but when the form is submitted you should obviously perform this validation once again.

Comment: Somehow it is counter intuitive because other validators do apply on the server side as well. Anyway thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov So It will not be executed on submit?